# test using same Bundle Identifier for different application cause trouble

Tags: ios, objective-c, cfbundleidentifier

I am testing applications on device, I used bundle identifier "mycompany.app" and after selecting proper code signing i am able to run the application on device(i.e my iPhone).
   Now after successfully run this application I deleted that and used the same bundleId and provisioning to test other application which is of local notifications. so it start showing the badge number on the application Icon whenever the local notification generated.
  Now again I deleted this application and try running my previous application with same bundle but it is showing the badge Number (ie 1) on application Icon even though I have not added any code for showing the badge Number to this application. How to remove these badge?

Comment: try restarting Xcode or clean your xcode project(command+shift+k). I hope this would help you in some way..

Comment: i did restart and cleaned too. but no hope.

Comment: please any other way to come out of situation?

Comment: I suggest you use different Bundle Identifier for different app. And now, I think reset your iPhone can resolve this problem(be careful, you will lose all your data).

Comment: ya,but for testing I had used the same one. now onwards i will use different bundle identifiers. btw resetting iPhone is not a good choice.

Comment: Try this out..delete the provisioning profile, download it form the developer account and install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi please use following code in

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

function:-

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

Comment: this trick works...but not getting why it was showing the badge Number even i had not added any code to set it. :)